# 3DPrinting question URLs aren't parsed in chat

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks

In chat rooms, questions from the 3DPrinting SE site aren't parsed correctly and just sit there as ugly URLs.

To illustrate here is a screenshot

> [image: 3DPrinting URL in chat]

It can be seen that the "Steering problem" question is displayed as expected, whereas the 3DPrinting URL (two lines below) is not parsed at all.

Apparently, it is because the errant URL starts with a number, i.e. "3".

Could this issue be fixed please?

Comment: @Sonictheinclusivehedgehog Nice to mark it duplicate, but what is the status of  the fix? Is there a way to circumvent the problem?