# User's name not being picked up by @@ superping suggestion in chat

Tags: bug, chat, moderator-tools, super-ping

I have a user, whose name is 2012User. When I try to superping them (`@@`) in the public 3DPrinting chatroom, with `@@2012`, their name does not appear in the *auto-complete user search suggestions box* thing<sup>1</sup>:

> [image: User search from superping]

They have a rep over over 100 (192), they have posted questions on the 3D Printing site, so they are an established user. Why is superping not working, or rather, why is their username not listed in the user suggestions?

Note that `@@13700@3dprinting.stackexchange.com` seems to make the user suggestion work correctly, but it is rather longwinded:

> [image: "User search from explicit superping"]

I do wonder if it is the old issue of 3DPrinting's site name causing issues again? See [3DPrinting question URLs aren't parsed in chat [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313879/3dprinting-question-urls-arent-parsed-in-chat)

I have tried pinging them with both `@@2012User` and `@@13700@3dprinting.stackexchange.com` but the latter doesn't appear to resolve the name correctly, and ends up looking like this

```
@@13700@3dprinting.stackexchange.com please join us in chat
```

whereas I'd expect it to look like:

```
@2012User please join us in chat
```

Also, I'm not sure if either of them (`@@2012User` or `@@13700@3dprinting.stackexchange.com`) worked as the user has not responded.

Note that other users with usernames beginning with numbers appear in the user suggestion just fine, as the first screen shot shows, just this particular user.

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't know the correct term for this UI component

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate; the answer is not mentioned anywhere in the target's answer. (It will be soon as I'll edit this there, citing this as a source, but it definitely didn't at the time this was asked and answered, and questions cited as sources for broader ones aren't duplicates of said broader ones.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Because the user doesn't have a chat account yet.

I just tried searching their username in the [list of all chat users](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/?tab=all&sort=activity) and got nothing:

[image]

Only users who already have chat accounts can be superpinged just by using `@@<username>`. For a user who has a *site* account but not yet an account on Chat.SE, you need to superping them using the `<userID>@<site>` syntax.